# Changing deltaTime of libgdx games

Tags: kotlin, libgdx, game-engine, game-physics, box

I want to pause my libgdx game which has box2d word. To pause game I decided manupilate the deltaTime.
I thought that if i assingn deltaTime to zero all rendering  codes can wait until press resume button. However deltaTime is not var it is val. So because of deltaTime is val, I am not able to reassign the value of deltaTime. Changing the deltaTime is forbidden. Is there any way to change the deltaTime.

Answer (score 0):

`deltaTime` is the measurement of the elapsed time since the last render, not a parameter.

You can stop (and start) rendering with

`Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);`

(This is usually used for when you want to determine how often to render with `Gdx.graphics.requestRender()` )

Note that this will stop **all rendering** so maybe instead just pause stepping the world in your call.

```
if (!isPaused) {
   box2DWorld.step(TIME_STEP_IN_SECONDS,
                   VELOCITY_ITERATIONS,
                   POSITION_ITERATIONS);
}
```